# Custom Post not working as expected

Tags: custom-post-types, php, variables

> **NEW EDIT** I solved it, as written in answer, the problem where that variables are 'forgotten' (not so techy I know, sorry for this) when
>   `function` starts.

**EDIT:** I found the problem is this: `'name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),`
if I use text instead of a variable everything works properly.... So, How can I use a variable here?

I am working on a new WordPress template using wptheming Option Framework.
User can choose how many custom posts he want (between 1 to 5) using a radio select.
The value of the radio is stored in DB and then, inside functions.php there is a require that 'includes' the proper PHP file. 
The 'include' works as expected ( I tryied to delete this: `<?php` at the beginning of each file and I can see the included files on top of my admin screen).
I thought that the problem could be the option not saved but, I tryied to echo each of them and I had no problem.
So I think that I am doing something wrong in the file that generates the cPosts.

This is what I have in functions.php:

```
/* Include Custom-posts settings */
if (of_get_option('custom_custom_post_creator')){//this is working
    $quanticpost = of_get_option('how_many_custom_posts');//this is working too
require_once MDCP_DIR . 'cpost/cpost_if_'.$quanticpost.'.php';//this is working too
};
```

This is cpost_if_5.php :

```
<?php
    /* IF 1 Start */
    $singcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_s_n1');
    $plurcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_p_n1');
    $desccpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_d_n1');
    $imgcpost  = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_i_n1');
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_1' );

function register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_1() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
        'singular_name' => _x( $singcpost, $singcpost ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', $singcpost ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search '.$plurcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found', $singcpost ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found in Trash', $singcpost ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent '.$singcpost.':', $singcpost ),
        'menu_name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => $desccpost,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'page-category', 'customtax1', 'customtax2', 'customtax3' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => $imgcpost,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( $singcpost, $args );
}
/* IF 1 END */
    /* IF 2 Start */
    $singcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_s_n2');
    $plurcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_p_n2');
    $desccpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_d_n2');
    $imgcpost  = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_i_n2');
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_2' );

function register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_2() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
        'singular_name' => _x( $singcpost, $singcpost ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', $singcpost ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search '.$plurcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found', $singcpost ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found in Trash', $singcpost ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent '.$singcpost.':', $singcpost ),
        'menu_name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => $desccpost,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'page-category', 'customtax1', 'customtax2', 'customtax3' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => $imgcpost,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( $singcpost, $args );
}
/* IF 2 END */
    /* IF 3 Start */
    $singcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_s_n3');
    $plurcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_p_n3');
    $desccpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_d_n3');
    $imgcpost  = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_i_n3');
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_3' );

function register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_3() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
        'singular_name' => _x( $singcpost, $singcpost ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', $singcpost ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search '.$plurcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found', $singcpost ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found in Trash', $singcpost ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent '.$singcpost.':', $singcpost ),
        'menu_name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => $desccpost,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'page-category', 'customtax1', 'customtax2', 'customtax3' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => $imgcpost,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( $singcpost, $args );
}
/* IF 3 END */
    /* IF 4 Start */
    $singcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_s_n4');
    $plurcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_p_n4');
    $desccpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_d_n4');
    $imgcpost  = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_i_n4');
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_4' );

function register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_4() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
        'singular_name' => _x( $singcpost, $singcpost ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', $singcpost ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search '.$plurcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found', $singcpost ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found in Trash', $singcpost ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent '.$singcpost.':', $singcpost ),
        'menu_name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => $desccpost,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'page-category', 'customtax1', 'customtax2', 'customtax3' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => $imgcpost,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( $singcpost, $args );
}
/* IF 4 END */
    /* IF 5 Start */
    $singcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_s_n5');
    $plurcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_p_n5');
    $desccpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_d_n5');
    $imgcpost  = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_i_n5');
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_5' );

function register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_5() {

    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
        'singular_name' => _x( $singcpost, $singcpost ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', $singcpost ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search '.$plurcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found', $singcpost ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found in Trash', $singcpost ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent '.$singcpost.':', $singcpost ),
        'menu_name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => $desccpost,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'page-category', 'customtax1', 'customtax2', 'customtax3' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => $imgcpost,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( $singcpost, $args );
}
/* IF 5 END */
    ;?>
```

This is what I see in Back-end even if, in theory, 5 custom posts are active.
[image: This is what I can see in the backend]

This is the url if I try to add a custom post:

> wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=

I think that the problem is related with my custom post code but I can't find what I did wrong.
Maybe variables aren't read as I thought by custom post code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I solved it, maybe instead of asking I should drink 1 more coffe or sleep something more, anyway the solution is to move this part:

```
$singcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_s_n1');
$plurcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_p_n1');
$desccpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_d_n1');
$imgcpost  = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_i_n1');
```

After the opening function...

Here is the corrected code:

```
<?php
    /* IF 1 Start */
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_1' );

function register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_1() {
    $singcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_s_n1');
    $plurcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_p_n1');
    $desccpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_d_n1');
    $imgcpost  = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_i_n1');
    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
        'singular_name' => _x( $singcpost, $singcpost ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', $singcpost ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search '.$plurcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found', $singcpost ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found in Trash', $singcpost ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent '.$singcpost.':', $singcpost ),
        'menu_name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => $desccpost,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'page-category', 'customtax1', 'customtax2', 'customtax3' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => $imgcpost,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( $singcpost, $args );
}
/* IF 1 END */
    /* IF 2 Start */
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_2' );

function register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_2() {
    $singcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_s_n2');
    $plurcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_p_n2');
    $desccpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_d_n2');
    $imgcpost  = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_i_n2');
    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
        'singular_name' => _x( $singcpost, $singcpost ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', $singcpost ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search '.$plurcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found', $singcpost ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found in Trash', $singcpost ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent '.$singcpost.':', $singcpost ),
        'menu_name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => $desccpost,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'page-category', 'customtax1', 'customtax2', 'customtax3' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => $imgcpost,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( $singcpost, $args );
}
/* IF 2 END */
    /* IF 3 Start */    
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_3' );

function register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_3() {
    $singcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_s_n3');
    $plurcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_p_n3');
    $desccpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_d_n3');
    $imgcpost  = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_i_n3');
    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
        'singular_name' => _x( $singcpost, $singcpost ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', $singcpost ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search '.$plurcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found', $singcpost ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found in Trash', $singcpost ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent '.$singcpost.':', $singcpost ),
        'menu_name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => $desccpost,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'page-category', 'customtax1', 'customtax2', 'customtax3' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => $imgcpost,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( $singcpost, $args );
}
/* IF 3 END */
    /* IF 4 Start */
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_4' );

function register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_4() {
    $singcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_s_n4');
    $plurcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_p_n4');
    $desccpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_d_n4');
    $imgcpost  = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_i_n4');
    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
        'singular_name' => _x( $singcpost, $singcpost ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', $singcpost ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search '.$plurcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found', $singcpost ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found in Trash', $singcpost ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent '.$singcpost.':', $singcpost ),
        'menu_name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => $desccpost,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'page-category', 'customtax1', 'customtax2', 'customtax3' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => $imgcpost,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( $singcpost, $args );
}
/* IF 4 END */
    /* IF 5 Start */
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_5' );

function register_cpt_cpost_mdframework_5() {
    $singcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_s_n5');
    $plurcpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_p_n5');
    $desccpost = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_d_n5');
    $imgcpost  = of_get_option('custom_posts_name_i_n5');
    $labels = array( 
        'name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
        'singular_name' => _x( $singcpost, $singcpost ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', $singcpost ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'New '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'View '.$singcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Search '.$plurcpost.'', $singcpost ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found', $singcpost ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No '.$plurcpost.' found in Trash', $singcpost ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent '.$singcpost.':', $singcpost ),
        'menu_name' => _x( $plurcpost, $singcpost ),
    );

    $args = array( 
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => $desccpost,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'custom-fields', 'comments', 'revisions', 'page-attributes' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag', 'page-category', 'customtax1', 'customtax2', 'customtax3' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => $imgcpost,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );

    register_post_type( $singcpost, $args );
}
/* IF 5 END */
    ;?>
```